# activate and paintied is not working in ext js

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, sencha-touch

There is a grid listing page in ext.

View :

```
Ext.define('App.view.client.ClientListView', {
    extend      : 'Ext.container.Container',
    xtype       : 'client-list',
    controller   : 'client',
    items:
    [
        {
            xtype   : 'panel',
            title   : 'Clients List',
            items   :
            [
                {
                    xtype       : 'grid',

                    columns: [
                        {
                            text        :'Mobile Number',
                            dataIndex   : 'mobile',
                          },
                        {
                            text        :'Email',
                            dataIndex   : 'email',
                          }
                     ],
                    store:Ext.create('dialgod.store.ClientStore'),
                    dockedItems:
                    [
                        {
                            xtype        : 'pagingtoolbar',
                            dock         : 'bottom',
                            displayInfo  : true
                        },
                        {
                            xtype     : 'toolbar',
                            height    : 50,
                            docked    : 'top',
                            items     :
                            [
                                {
                                    xtype    : 'button',
                                    text     : 'Add Client',
                                    name     : 'btn_add_client',
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

});

controller :

```
Ext.define('App.controller.ClientController', {
extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
alias: 'controller.client',
init: function() {
    this.control({
        'client-list':
        {
            activate    : this.loadClientsList,
            painted     : this.loadClientsList
        },
        'client-list button[name=btn_add_client]':{
            click   : this.AddClientForm
        },

    });
},

loadClientsList: function(listObj)
{
    console.log("loading client");
    var storeObj    = listObj.down("grid").getStore();
    storeObj.load();
},


AddClientForm : function(){
    console.log("client add form clicked");
    }
```

all the **click function** is working fine in this controller. 
**activate, painted** both are not working.
i m not able to console to this activate function while loading the grid page. so there  is not initializing to load this grid. so any solution for activate, painted os not correct or anything else to use load? anyone can suggest please.

Comment: Are you using extjs or sencha-touch framework, what version?

Answer (score 1):

In ExtJs classic toolkit:
'activate' event of the Ext.container.Container "This event is only fired if this Component is a child of a Ext.container.Container that uses Ext.layout.container.Card as it's layout or this Component is a floating Component.". You are not using card layout in the Component.
'painted' event I have found in the Sencha Touch but at the same time the Ext.container.Container is not a class of sencha touch.
Anyway, you can use 'render' or 'show' (grid.show()/hide()) events to load your store.
Your controller will have the following look:

```
...
...
init: function() {
    this.control({
        'client-list':
        {
            render: this.loadClientsList,
            //show: this.loadClientsList fires in case of visual show/hide
        },
        'client-list button[name=btn_add_client]':{
            click   : this.AddClientForm
        },

    });
},
...
...
```